# Optimization , window.setInterval or .change function on range

Tags: javascript, input, range, setinterval

am kinda having thoughts here that setInterval function on 50ms is bad? Or i am wrong... So this is situation here, i have a input range, and i want to get value of that range on change.. so i have this two codes..

```
$('#transparency-range').change(function(){
   $(".transparency-color span").text($('#transparency-range').val() + "%")
 })
```

// 2nd code

```
window.setInterval(function(){
  $(".transparency-color span").text($('#transparency-range').val() + "%")
}, 50);
```

Is first code better for optimization maybe? 
Problem with first code is that i dont get live info of value, so in my text field that i want to show that info, numbers change only when i finish change, 
while with second code, am getting numbers changing while i am moving range input..

I am using similiar code more than 10 times in application, thats why this optimization question is kinda important :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `setInterval` is a bad choice for tracking input change, since it is not synced with the actual change in the input, it lives it's own life, and very importantly needs clearing up with `clearInterval` and clogs event loop up with unnecessary executions thus making your overall app much slower.
2. The better approach would be to listen to input's specific events like `change`, `input`, `keyup`, `keypress`, `keydown`. They were specifically designed to handle such cases and that's why there is a variety of them.

So if we go with `input`, it will look like this:

```js
$('#transparency-range').on('input', function(){
   $(".transparency-color span").text($(this).val() + "%");
});
```

This will give you an immediate change feedback after you type each character.

3. This still doesn't free you from not clearing up your event listener, but at least now your event listener is specifically tracking a input change and not just executing in a interval.

You can do that with:

```js
function inputHandler() {
  $(".transparency-color span").text($(this).val() + "%");
}

$('#transparency-range').on('input', inputHandler);

//...
// later in you code when needed
$('#transparency-range').off('input', inputHandler);
```

4. And last but not least, since your question is about optimization,
   there is this practice of [debouncing](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce/examples/debounce/) a function call, which in your situation will give you the best of both worlds, you will still have delayed execution, that you can control, but now it will happen as you type and not on blur.

With the aforementioned plugin, if you need to execute your function on after 250ms from user having stopped typing it can go something like this:

```js
function inputHandler() {
  $(".transparency-color span").text($(this).val() + "%");
}

$('#transparency-range').on('input', $.debounce(250, inputHandler));
```

Answer (score 0):

You might get better results if you listen to the `input` event, which triggers with every change, immediately:

```
$('#transparency-range').on('input', function(){
   $(".transparency-color span").text($('#transparency-range').val() + "%");
});
```

If this does the job, then it is certainly preferable over using a timer.